# Could any one tell me what the difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url-pattern?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

we can define a servlet in web.xml and specify the url-pattern， I often specify the url-pattern into `"/*"`， but in Spring MVC，it‘s value is `"/"`，if I use `"/*"`， I even couldn't visit the welcome file，so any one could tell me what the difference between `/` and `/*` , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by Mohamed the issue may be elesewhere. Generally speaking

1. `/` means exactly `http://localhost/`
2. `/*` means  `http://localhost/<whatever>`

the question must be a little bit refined, if you are configuring `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` a typical pattern should be *.do or you cannot access pure html page.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your welcome file list specified in web.xml. I've faced a similar situation before. When I named my welcome file as index.jsp and had many other additional names (like index.html, etc) mentioned in web.xml. When I removed all of them except index.jsp, it worked. I'm not sure if it would work for you. Please give it a try and post your feedback.